# Is there a better way to implement a search on an array containing structured data?

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, dynamic

I commonly encounter the need to dynamically create an array of objects containing specific data, which also requires the need for a search method, for example:

**Javascript**

```
var people = [];
var addPerson = function(name, age) {
    people.push({name:name, 
                 age:age});
}
getArrayID = function (name) {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < main.nodes.length ; i++) {
        if(main.nodes[i].name == name)
            return i;
    }    
    return -1;
}

addPerson("Person A", 22);
addPerson("Person B", 23);
console.log(people[getArrayID("PersonB")].age);
// Result: 23
```

Although this works, it just feels like it's the improper solution to the issue of having 'labelled' pieces of data, as it usually also includes a getArrayName(id) method.

If possible, I'd like to see a solution in a 'loose' language like **Javascript** (where objects and arrays can be named with strings), and in a more strict language like **C++** or **Java**.

Comment: Asking for this is two different languages is not a good idea. It's like asking two questions in one, which means you'll get some answers focusing more on one, others focusing more on the other. Why not ask for one language first, and then, if still needed and meaningful, post a second question for the other one?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what to ask here. As such it is off topic and belongs at perhaps codereview

Comment: @jogojapan I am both interested in a simplified solution, and the common ways of handling this issue, as I imagine this is a common function in any program that would be working with dynamic arrays. I am a self-taught programmer, so learning solutions in addition the theory behind the solution interests me, it's not a matter of just seeing how to do it in X and Y language, but how, from a computer science perspective, this would best be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  Use lodash.  With it, you can simplify this way down:

```
var person = _.find(people, { "name": "Person B" });
if (person !== undefined) {
    var age = 'age' in person ? person.age:'not available';
    console.log('Age: ',age);
} else {
    console.log("Couldn't find that guy");
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/c2nnknsh/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do this.

**[[].find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**:

```js
var people = [];
var addPerson = function(name, age) {
  people.push({
    name: name,
    age: age
  });
}

// will return ONE person or null
getPerson = function(name) {
  return people.find(function(person) {
    return person.name == name;
  });
}

addPerson("Person A", 22);
addPerson("Person B", 23);

var pers = getPerson("Person B");
// we must check pers is not null/undefined
if (pers) {
  console.log(pers.age);
  document.write(pers.age);
}
```

**[[].filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**:

```js
var people = [];
var addPerson = function(name, age) {
  people.push({
    name: name,
    age: age
  });
}

// will return an array of persons (can be empty)
getPerson = function(name) {
  return people.filter(function(person) {
    return person.name == name;
  });
}

addPerson("Person A", 22);
addPerson("Person B", 23);

var pers = getPerson("Person B")[0];
// we must check pers is not null/undefined
if (pers) {
  console.log(pers.age);
  document.write(pers.age);
}
```

Comment: yeah, good point that you need to confirm 'pers' in not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If persons are unique by their `name` I would go for using an `object` instead of an array. This way you do not have to search an entire array every time and profit from native 'search performance'.

Something like this:

```
var people = {}; 
var addPerson = function(name, age) { 
    people[name] = {name:name, age:age}; 
} 
addPerson("Person A", 22);
addPerson("Person B", 23); 
var person = people["PersonB"];
console.log(person && person.age); // Result: 23
```

Answer (score 0):

In *Javascript*, you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for a mixed purpose, like only return the index or a special pattern.

This solution features an object with the search parameter, like the property to search on and the value to look for. The result is an array with the indices of all matching patterns of the array.

```js
function setCondition(condition) {
    var key = Object.keys(condition)[0],
        value = condition[key];
    return function (r, a, i) {
        if (a[key] === value) {
            r.push(i);
        }
        return r;
    }
}

var people = [{ name: 'Person A', age: 22 }, { name: 'Person B', age: 23 }],
    indices = people.reduce(setCondition({ name: 'Person B' }), []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(indices, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```